# Dimensions of input layer for a multilayer perceptron

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, keras

I have been training a multilayer perceptron using Keras to make a prediction on a function similar to that of a normal distribution. I have $4$ input variables $(w,x,y,z)$, and I have one output value $f(w,x,y,z)$.

When I set my input layer to have $4$ neurons as such

```
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=4, activation= 'relu'))
```

the model learns with a $60\%$ accuracy.

When I tried to use $35$ neurons in my input layer as such

```
model.add(Dense(35, input_dim=4, activation= 'relu'))
```

my model learns it with an $88\%$ accuracy.

I'm not understanding the logic behind this. Surely you have to have only $4$ neurons for the input layer; what is happening with the other $31$ neurons?

Answer (score 3):

The input "layer" always has 4 neurons. It's not really a layer because it does no computation. What your code specifies is whether the first real (hidden) layer has 4 or 35 neurons.